# What chat implementation has the least impact on server performance?

Tags: php, performance, chat

I'm making a tiny little chat option for a web app, and I'm wondering what would be the best place to keep data, to have the least performance issues. Is it better to keep the chat:

1. in a MySQL database
2. in an SqLite database
3. a local JSON file

It is my guess that MySQL would be the slowest. But, do the other options have some kind of protection against overwriting messages that come in at the same time? With MySQL for example, I can easily just `INSERT` messages and they will end up in the database, because the database itself takes care about table locking. But if I go with the plain local file option, then writing into the same file at the same time because two people sent a message at the same time, could get them overwritten, right? Which makes the entire solution unstable, regardless of whether it has best performance. And for SqLite I'm not sure how it works in that regard.

Comment: Typically a real database server will a thousand times outperform any file based solution like sqlite or json storage files.

Comment: Least impact would be a simple message router. Why does a database need to be involved at all? You don't necessarily want to *store* messages, you want to *distribute* messages in as close to real time as possible. For that, a constant connection to each client (e.g. web socket) would be preferable, and you simply push each message to each relevant client immediately. Which would make the speed of the database irrelevant.

Comment: @deceze Are you suggesting not storing messages at all? As in, when you log in next time, all your previous conversations are gone? Because I don't think that would be acceptable for users nowadays. Except if I misunderstood you.

Comment: @ImNotMike That's exactly what I'm proposing **as the basic architecture**. If you want *message archival*, you can add that by using a database, a *proper* database. But a *long term data storage mechanism* should not factor into the architecture of your *real time message distribution mechanism*.

Comment: @deceze I'm trying to wrap my head around your suggestion, which I do like in theory, but wouldn't the messages still have to reside somewhere in the meanwhile between the sender, and the recipient, e.g. a file? Otherwise you'd need to have as many socket connections open, as there are online users.. which is not that viable, is it?

Comment: Yes, as many open connections as there are users. That's very viable (with the right software; not sure how well PHP would fare TBH). More viable than a *polling architecture* in which each client constantly bombards the server with new HTTP requests and creates and tears down a connection all the time.